# RefreshView is pushing content to right in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, .net-maui

Came across this strange behavior in .NET MAUI app while testing it on an iOS device.

First, everything looks fine on Android -- both emaulator and physical device. I then noticed this issue in iOS Simulator and have the same results on my iPhone.

If I have no `RefreshView` around my `CollectionView`, the empty view message display where it's supposed -- well almost because I can never place it in the center of the page vertically but other than that, it displays correctly -- see below:

[image]

If I do place my `CollectionView` within a `RefreshView`, the `Label` gets pushed to the right -- see below:

[image]

Here's the actual code with the `RefreshView`. All you need to do is remove `RefreshView` and label is displayed in the center.

```
<RefreshView
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
        Command="{Binding RefreshCouponsCommand}">
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="MyCouponsList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feed}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <VerticalStackLayout
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label
                        Text="No data..."
                        TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: See original post now

Comment: Just tested it with a fresh new MAUI app and looks like `RefreshView` is definitely screwing up the alignment of its child content

Comment: Looks like it's an open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7315

Comment: does the same happen with a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
<CollectionView
            x:Name="MyCouponsList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feed}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                <VerticalStackLayout
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Label
                        Text="No data..."
                        TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </CollectionView.EmptyView>
        </CollectionView>
```

with

```
<CollectionView
            x:Name="MyCouponsList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Feed}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            EmptyView="No Data..."/>
            
        </CollectionView>
```